# why is Eclipse file > new > android application project producing a gutted folder with different folder icons?

Tags: android, eclipse, project

I was doing some clean up of bloatware and files that I could recognize as unnecessary.

When I started eclipse juno 4.2 afterward, the new android application button produced a completely different folder than I was used to.
The icons are completely different. Instead of folders, they are black and white icons.
The only files that are made inside of the folder are styles.xml and strings.xml.
The src, gen and assets folders are empty.

I am a new user and cant post images yet, but here is the picture of what is occurring:
[image]

Since this problem I have restored everything that could possibly have caused this. And rebooted of course.
I have also tried deleting the entire eclipse folder and unzipping it newly into program files.

The only way I have found to produce a correct project is to uncheck the []Create Custom Launcher box in the New Android App dialog. Then it seems to come out correctly. It's also worth noting that the MOTODEV > New > New Android Application button still works correctly and produces a standard project.

I would like to know if anybody has information on what I have to reinstall to get everything functioning correctly again. Or if there is a simpler fix.

Comment: When you created the project, did you elect to create an activity? If not, your output is more or less what I would expect.

Comment: Yes, the third page of the New Android Application dialog does have [] Creat Activity checked.

Answer (score 0):

my sense is that this is a feature, not a bug.  the MOTODEV resources are probably still the "old" resources.

but notice carefully that not all of those icons are the same.

the 'black and white' icon that you site appears to me to be some sort of attempt to show a graphics item, like a crosshairs or layout or something.

the assets, gen, libs and res folders have the little android 'a' next to them, much like your outer project folder and the document icon for the AndroidManifest.xml .

notice that the items that have contents, like lib and res, have tiny folders in the lower right corner.  this seems to be an indication that these local resources have content, where the others do not yet.  i wonder if, once you've created a bit of code in your project and done something that will fill the gen folder, if it will end up with the same icon.

my guess is that the way to "fix" this problem is going to be to back out to the previous version of the SDK/eclipse.

Comment: Those icons aren't an artifact of the MOTODEV plugins, at least not in any of the configurations that I have installed. I take it this workspace existed prior to using Eclipse 4.2? There could be some "schmutz" hanging around in there. I'll have one of the guys check in on this Monday.  In the mean time, a period "window>reset perspective" is worth a try...

Comment: @John & Eric: I tried all of the things you both suggested. This version was working for a few weeks, and only started doing this recently, after I was clearing programs. The program will not even allow me to add activities using Right-Click>New>Android Activity- I cannot select the src folder of the newly created project. Without a src activity, what can it do anyway? I tried creating a brand new workspace folder but still the same.